# How to print value of C macro in configure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, autotools, autoconf

I have `configure.in` script. I want to invoke `configure` ( after `autoheader && autoconf` ) and see value of `PAGE_SHIFT` macro from system header `page_types.h`. Something like this:

`checking PAGE_SHIFT... 12`

I've tried those:

1.

```
AC_CHECK_DECL([PAGE_SHIFT],[HAVE_PAGE_SHIFT=$PAGE_SHIFT],[],
[#include <linux/module.h>])
AC_MSG_NOTICE([${HAVE_PAGE_SHIFT}])
```

Result: macro `PAGE_SHIFT` was detected, but haven't been printed

```
checking whether PAGE_SHIFT is declared... yes
configure:
```

2.

```
HAVE_PAGE_SHIFT="Unknown"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([PAGE_SHIFT])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(
[
AC_LANG_PROGRAM([
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stdio.h>
],
[
printf("%d\n", PAGE_SHIFT);
])],
[HAVE_PAGE_SHIFT="$PAGE_SHIFT"], [])
AC_MSG_RESULT([${HAVE_PAGE_SHIFT}])
```

Result: doesn't work

```
checking PAGE_SHIFT...
```

3.

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(['PAGE_SHIFT' value])
AC_RUN_IFELSE(
[
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{

    printf("%d\n", PAGE_SHIFT);
    return 0;
}
]
)
```

Result: works, but can't be used with cross-compile

```
checking 'PAGE_SHIFT' value... 12
```

4. method was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957121/5247040) by Brett Hale

Autoconf will generate something like this:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
static long int longval () { return PAGE_SHIFT; }
static unsigned long int ulongval () { return PAGE_SHIFT; }
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Result: doesn't work with kernel headers

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
             from conftest.c:125:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:44:18: error: conflicting types for 'loff_t'
typedef __loff_t loff_t;
              ^
In file included from /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h:5:0,
             from [...],
             from conftest.c:121:
/lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/types.h:45:26: note: previous declaration of 'loff_t' was here
typedef __kernel_loff_t  loff_t;
```

Autoconf version: autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`AC_COMPUTE_INT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Generic-Compiler-Characteristics) macro. e.g.,

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(['PAGE_SHIFT' value])

AC_COMPUTE_INT([PAGE_SHIFT_VAL], [PAGE_SHIFT], [[#include <linux/module.h>]],
  AC_MSG_FAILURE([linux/module.h: could not determine 'PAGE_SHIFT' value]))

AC_MSG_RESULT([$PAGE_SHIFT_VAL])
```

Alternatively, you can replace the `FAILURE` macro with `PAGE_SHIFT_VAL=0` and test that value for `(0)` if the error is recoverable.

Note that there's nothing magical about the variable name `PAGE_SHIFT_VAL`, in this context; you can use another name. You still need the `AC_SUBST` if you want this value substituted in generated files, like `config.h`, or those listed in `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

Comment: Thank you. Your method doesn't work with kernel headers. Autoconf made this code `#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
[...]`
Result:
`In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from conftest.c:125:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:44:18: error: conflicting types for 'loff_t'
In file included from [...],
                 from conftest.c:121:
/lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/types.h:45:26: note: previous declaration of 'loff_t' was here
`

Comment: @RomanZaytsev - You need to know how the Linux build Makefile works, and how to setup kernel (cross) compilation - which is 'freestanding' - with gcc include paths, `CFLAGS`, sysroot options, etc.

Comment: It seems my question is too broad and depends on cross-compile flags, etc. I'm accepting your answer because it's correct for non-kernel headers.